# ARC Semantic iOS Compile in XCode Issue

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, cocoapods, mixpanel

We are trying to figure out how to solve this issue. See the compile error here.

[image: https://content.screencast.com/users/matt_buzz/folders/Jing/media/7d727720-3338-4174-a140-ae54d5d52e61/00000514.png]

Comment: Error is in MixPanel.m file, please add the code where you are getting the error

Comment: Will provide shortly @midhu

Comment: @MidhunMP  Here is the link to the mixpanel.m file for your review:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-hFokTVTtyTNEdacllURlBzb0E

Comment: Issue will be in this line : `MPEventBinding *binder = [MPEventBinding bindingWithJSONObject:obj];`. Check whether `MPEventBinding` class contain any such method.